# Transfer data from Data Grid View to another form that contains only Data Grid View

Tags: c#, database, forms, datagridview, transfer

I have a form that contains datagridview only (it does not contain text boxes).. I want to transfer one of the rows in it to another form that contains only datagridview via radio button

I use the Visual Studio program to design the forms and the Sql server program to store the database.. and each form has a table dedicated to it inside the database that contains the same number of columns for the forms

Comment: Can you please post some code so that somebody can help you?

Comment: I don't understand what kind of code to post

Comment: You can post code related to forms and radio button that you are working on. Without code it is next to impossible to provide you a solution.